# Matrix size-incompatible between Flatten and Dense layer

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to implement multi-agent A2C algorithm with Keras.
There is an issue when I use Keras backend function (K.fuction).

I gave input whose shape is (None, 3, 4, 5).
This input passes through `Flatten()`, and then it is connected to `Dense()`.

It works fine when I use `model.predict(input)`, but a problem happened when I use customized optimizer using K.function.

I gave input whose shape is (1000, 3, 4, 5) into `model.input` in K.function, but Matrix size-incompatible error appear:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Matrix size-incompatible: In[0]: [3,20], In[1]: [60,64]
    [[{{node dense_1/Relu}}]]
```

It looks `Flatten()` doesn't work properly.

Network looks like this:

```
def build_network(self):
    inp = Input(shape=(3,4,5))
    x = Flatten()(inp)
    x = Dense(64, activation='relu')(x)
    x = Dense(128, activation='relu')(x)
    x = Dense(128, activation='relu')(x)
    out = Dense(9, activation='softmax')(x)

    return Model(inp, out)

self.model = self.build_network()
```

*model.summary()* :
[image]

The customized optimizer is here:

```
import keras.backend as K

def optimizer(self):
    weighted_actions = K.sum(self.action_pl * self.model.ouput, axis=1)
    eligibility = K.log(weighted_actions + 1e-10) * K.stop_gradient(self.advantages_pl)
    entropy = K.sum(self.model.output * K.log(self.model.output + 1e-10), axis=1)
    loss = 0.001 * entropy - K.sum(eligibility)

    _out = K.zeros(shape=(1))
    updates = self.rms_optimizer.get_updates(self.model.trainable_weights, [], loss)

    return K.fucntion([self.model.input, self.action_pl, self.advantages_pl], _out, updates=updates)

self.opt = self.optimizer()

self.opt([input, actions, advantages]) # Error occured here. input.shape = (1000,3,4,5)
```

I don't know why it happens and how to solve this issue.

Any advice will be appreciated.

Environment:
Ubuntu16.04
Python2.7
Keras: 2.3.0
tensorflow 1.14.0

Comment: Are you sure you are not passing an input of size (3, 4, 5) instead? This would be consistent with your error as Flatten would reshape it to (3, 20). Can you show the rest of the code?

Answer (score 0):

Issue seems to be that the input is taking of shape [3,20], but it should have been [1000, 60] after flatten.

Please check the shape of your input. Also you can use

```
tf.expand_dims(
    input,
    axis,
    name=None
)
```

to add dimension for your input and try. It should resolve your issue.